# How to get the pprint output as string and not printed on stdout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pprint

In python 3.6.8 I want to have the output of a `pprint` not been printed to the screen (e.g `stdout`), but I want that output as a string in a variable.

I tried the following (complete example):

```
import io
import pprint

d = {'cell_type': 'code',
   'execution_count': None,
   'metadata': {'collapsed': True, 'trusted': True},
   'outputs': []
}
f = io.StringIO()
pprint.pprint(dict, f)
print(f.read())
```

but I just got an empty string. I was expecting an output

```
{'cell_type': 'code',
 'execution_count': None,
 'metadata': {'collapsed': True, 'trusted': True},
 'outputs': []}
```

instead.

Maybe there is an easier way to achieve this without streams?

In the end I want to compare two very complex dictionaries to see their differences. My idea: Generate a string version of the dict and compare that (with something like a bash `diff`).

Comment: Why dont you simply use `str_d = str(d)`?

Comment: another solution is to use the json module. import json then use json.dumps(d) to get a string representation of your dict.

Comment: Because then I still have the one dict in one single piece of text, which I can hardly compare to another dict.

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to compare two dicts. And I have them already in two files, but they have one single line each (with length 20000). Comparing those files as they are is meaningless

Comment: @Alex You're comparing them yourself, manually?

Comment: Nope, I want a proper diff with a tool or a command or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not moved your file pointer prior to read.

```
f = io.StringIO()
pprint.pprint(d, f) # note: pass d and not dict
f.seek(0) # move pointer to start of file
print(f.read())
```

or just

```
print(f.getvalue())
```